# Text view set text not working

Tags: java, android

```
TextView textViewprompt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textViewprompt2.setText("There will be a series of 10 questions");
    TextView textViewprompt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textViewprompt1.setText("There will be a series of 10 questions");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    TextView textViewcountdown1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView textViewcountdown2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textViewcountdown1.setText("3");
    textViewcountdown2.setText("3");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    textViewcountdown1.setText("2");
    textViewcountdown2.setText("2");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    textViewcountdown1.setText("1");
    textViewcountdown2.setText("1");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    textViewcountdown1.setText("Go");
    textViewcountdown2.setText("Go");
    Thread.sleep(500);
```

why wont this work it basically skips over the setText and only seems to execute the Thread.sleep() lines

Comment: Is this block of code inside a try catch block?

Comment: Try to skip creating two additional TextViews and, instead of that, use previously created TextViews (textViewprompt1 & textViewprompt2).

Comment: not working because calling `Thread.sleep` on UI Thread

Comment: you are blocking the main thread. incidentaly, that's the thread used to make the drawing part. No releasing the thread, no text is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Thread.sleep()` sleeps the same Thread as is used by `setText()` and that's why your TextViews don't update.

I would reccomend to use Timer (especially CountDownTimer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) to update your TextView with delay, instead of Thread.sleep.

Comment: even if i take out the Thread.sleep() it still wont work                      TextView textViewprompt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textViewprompt2.setText("There will be a series of 10questions");this doesnt even work

Comment: Where do you call the problematic code? I think that calling it in Activity's onCreate() should be OK, but it could not work if you call that from some other thread.